# How to pass an Input value to Action stage in Blue Prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am testing a Launch NotePad application in Blue Prism. I need to pass "Hello World" text as Input Value from the Action Stage in Process Studio to Object Studio. I can't find the write Action in Action Properties. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have action from object visible in process studio, then you need to publish it.

Right click on the action tab in the object and choose "publish".